# Can I use a Library when making a OS

Tags: c, operating-system

I want to make a OS in C but for many of the simple functions you need the stdio.c library(I understand that I could just make a the functions myself but I’m kinda lazy and this is just a hobby, I don’t have much free time) I also want use another library GTK+. So, can I use libraries when making a OS?

Comment: The purpose of the C library is to provide the abstraction layer between a C program, and the OS that it's running on. So if you want to use an existing implementation of `stdio`, then your OS needs to emulate an existing OS.

Comment: Writing an OS from scratch is going to need opposite of lazy as that is a deep dive task. And no, it's unlikely that you can use most user level libraries within a native OS.

Comment: As it has been pointed out, the correct answer would be "it depend". OS dependent libraries are unsable without the OS (stdio for example), while library that provide OS independent function could be used, sometime you would have to provide function from your OS to be able to use the library